# Lights not showing in viewport or render

Tags: rendering, objects, 3d-view, lighting

I'm currently working on a project in which I am trying to add different lights to. I've added a sun light, spotlight and point light and none of them are showing up in the viewport or render. I have an obj which I imported from procreate, I don't know if that has anything to do with it. I've tried multiple solutions and none of them have worked. Would greatly appreciate any suggestions
[image: here's a picture of my project]

EDIT: here's a link to my project file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D_QpjvbtZDWmUyvZYDe0UaDU9rMrYbyu/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @vklidu Hi, thank you for your response. I'm relatively new to blender, how do I check whether I have plugged an image texture directly to the output node or emission node?

Comment: @vklidu I've checked and I'm pretty sure the image texture isn't directly plugged into my output node. I've added an edit to my question with the link to my project file. Would really appreciate it if you could take a look at It and offer any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cube** is too big (200 m) ... I would highly suggest to you - scale it down to get more natural dimension for this thing. You avoid a lot of other issues, like Camera clipping (that you are facing with already) etc.

**Green Light** - your Spot light is like a bulb light with power set to 100 W now, that is still too low to be able light surface so far (300 m). I had to set 100.000 W to get some effect. If you switch this light to Sun type (under properties) you can see light is lightning.

### For quick fix

- switch *Transform Pivot Point* in top header of *3Dview editor* to type **Cursor**

[image]

- place the **Cursor to World Origin** <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
- Select all <kbd>A</kbd> and **Scale** <kbd>S</kbd> to 0.1 (just type the numbers)

[image]

Like that you get a Cube 2 m, that is probably still too much for such thing, but you can already see lights affecting cube's surface. Here Green light set to 1000 W.

Anyway I see you have quite a lot of other strong lights. Would be helpful to turn all lights off (in Outliner (Eye icon)) and turn ON one by one to see how they work and affects your scene, some of them are not probably needed.

Comment: For short: scales matter. Don't expect a bicycle lamp to light up the Eiffel Tower.

Comment: Hohooo ... Great title :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I am able to see the lights now. I do have one more question though if it's alright. In your last image, the green light seems to be focused on the right corner of the cube the remainder is in the shadows. I am trying to have the same effect on my object but the light illuminates the entire face of the cube. Is it because it a sunlight and is there a way for me to work around it?

Comment: Sorry I'm out of comp now ... But yes, sun running with your camera is too strong. Play with power of lights or multiply some gradient mask in postprocess on rendered anim, but it would not look realistic, but can worth from artistic point of view ;)

Comment: @vklidu alright, I'll play around with it some more. Thank you so much for your help :).